# Airflow Unit test querying non-existent db: no such table: slot_pool

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, pytest

I am trying to unit test (tox+pytest) using a mock dag.  Usually I haven't had an issue but whenever I add a subdag into the mix I get a sql error.  For additional context, I also have a custom library that also creates a subdag during testing and that doesn't trigger any errors.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: slot_pool
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to get around this issue?

My mock code is here.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_dag():
    dag = DAG(
    "my_dag",
    default_args={
      "start_date": datetime(2021, 7, 15),
    },
  )

    sub_dag = DAG(
      dag_id="my_dag.my_subdag",
      params=dag.params,
      start_date=datetime(2021, 7, 15),
      schedule_interval=dag.schedule_interval,
      default_args=dag.default_args,
      template_searchpath=dag.template_searchpath,
      user_defined_macros=dag.user_defined_macros,
    )
    sub_dag.is_subdag = True
    DummyOperator(task_id="test", dag=sub_dag)
    SubDagOperator(
      task_id="my_subdag",
      subdag=sub_dag,
      default_args=dag.default_args,
      dag=dag,
    )
    return dag
```

Full stack trace:

```
    return __inject_session_to_func(func, session_type, *args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py:72: in __inject_session_to_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py:98: in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py:84: in __init__
    .filter(Pool.pool == self.pool)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3429: in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3203: in __getitem__
    return list(res)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3535: in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3560: in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1011: in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:298: in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1130: in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1317: in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1511: in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:182: in raise_
    raise exception
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1277: in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlite.SQLiteDialect_pysqlite object at 0x106c77e80>, cursor = <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x11efdc110>
statement = 'SELECT slot_pool.id AS slot_pool_id, slot_pool.pool AS slot_pool_pool, slot_pool.slots AS slot_pool_slots, slot_pool....iption AS slot_pool_description \nFROM slot_pool \nWHERE slot_pool.slots = ? AND slot_pool.pool = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'
parameters = (1, 'default_pool', 1, 0), context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteExecutionContext object at 0x11efd69b0>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: slot_pool
E       [SQL: SELECT slot_pool.id AS slot_pool_id, slot_pool.pool AS slot_pool_pool, slot_pool.slots AS slot_pool_slots, slot_pool.description AS slot_pool_description 
E       FROM slot_pool 
E       WHERE slot_pool.slots = ? AND slot_pool.pool = ?
E        LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
E       [parameters: (1, 'default_pool', 1, 0)]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.p
```